# Motion correction (image stabilization) softwares/libraries

Tags: gratis, library, python, c++, image-processing

I have fluorescence recording from population of neurons [sample video on youtube](https://youtu.be/0EJ9jVktFu8). The problem is that camera had vibrations making each frame shifts a little in x-y direction. Additionally recording has noise but that will improve.

I am looking for a open-source solution to correct such a shift. The open-source nature is mandatory so that I can extend it to my requirements later. I am comfortable with python, c/c++, java and Haskell. So a solution in any of these languages would be OK but preference is for python.

In case the application is closed-source but free of cost, the I/O format should not be propriety.

## I/O formats

- Any format which `ffmpeg`/opencv can read on linux platform (ubuntu/openSUSE) e.g. tiff, avi, mp4, mkv
- Output - In addition to common video/image formats, I am also ok with hdf5, npy, and python pickle format.

## Potential candidates

- [SIMA - Sequential IMage Analysis](http://www.losonczylab.org/sima/1.3.2/) . It has [motion corretion](http://www.losonczylab.org/sima/1.3.2/tutorial.html#motion-correction) functionality. Open-source and  python based. It was very easy to install. Currently testing.

Comment: Would you mind showing a small sample of your files, to make sure what data you have? Thanks!

Comment: Also what input & output formats are you looking at - is the input a singe video file or multiple still images & should the output be a single video or multiple position corrected images.

Comment: Added  a sample video and some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to code posted [here](http://nghiaho.com/?p=2093), I managed to cook-up my own application. It is written in c++ and uses opencv and libtiff. The performance is very good. See the results [here](https://youtu.be/vGjIFvzOOQ8).

The application is hosted on github https://github.com/dilawar/video_stabilizer.